# Replace specific chinese punctuations with correspondent english ones in Python

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, string, dataframe

Given a test dataset as follows:

```
   id                   company
0   1                  xyz，ltd。
1   2  wall street english （bj）
2   3                 James（sh）
3   4                       NaN
4   5                    黑石（上海）
```

I need to replace chinese punctutations with correspondent english one: `(` for `（`,  `)` for `）`, `.` for `。` and `,` for `，`.

I try with `dd.company.str.replace('（', '(').replace('）', ')').replace('。', '.').replace('，', ',')`, it's not pythonic solution and not work out either.

Out:

```
0                    xyz，ltd。
1    wall street english (bj）
2                   James(sh）
3                         NaN
4                      黑石(上海）
Name: company, dtype: object
```

How could I replace them correctly? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would simply use `unidecode` here. Unless you really have some strange requirement to only deal with one or two chars, `unidecode` is a universal solution for this. It can be combined with regex, say, you match only punctuation, or non-letters, and then run `unidecode` on the match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is use `2 lists` or dictionary and pass `regex=True` for substring replacement:

```
dd.company.replace(['（','）', '。', '，'], ['(',')','.', ','], regex=True)
```

---

```
dd.company.replace({'（':'）', '(':')', '。':'.', '，':','}, regex=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it raises an error for your second solution `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend matching any punctuation (say, with `[^\w\s]` regex that matches any non-word and non-whitespace chars) and apply the [`unidecode`](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/) on the match:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import unidecode
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5], 'company': ['xyz，ltd。', 'wall street english （bj）', 'James（sh）', np.NaN, '黑石（上海）']})
df['company'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', lambda x: unidecode.unidecode(x.group()))
>>> df['company'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', lambda x: unidecode.unidecode(x.group()))
0                   xyz,ltd. 
1    wall street english (bj)
2                   James(sh)
3                         NaN
4                      黑石(上海)
Name: company, dtype: object
```